# Троичное дерево: ошибка

Tags: java

Написала код троичного дерева.

```
public class Tree {

    public Tree right;
    public Tree left;
    public Tree middle;
    public int key;

    public Tree(int k) {
        key = k;
    }

    public void add(Tree aTree) {

        if (right == null) {
            right = aTree;
        }
        if (middle == null) {
            middle = aTree;
        }
        if (left == null) {
            left = aTree;
        }

        if (left != null) {
            left.add(aTree);
        }
        if (middle != null) {
            middle.add(aTree);
        }
        if (right != null) {
            right.add(aTree);
        }
        System.out.print(" " + aTree.key);
    }

}
```

Возникает ошибка в этом месте, не могу понять почему.

```
if (left != null) {
    left.add(aTree);
}
```

Comment: Еще хорошо бы показать, как вы обращаетесь к этому дереву. И возникающее исключение. `NullPointerException`?

Comment: воспользуйтесь конструкцией if-else if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть проблемка в алгоритме. Возникнет ситуация, когда вы добавили `aTree` в качестве листа, после этого `right` будет уже не `null` и вы добавите `aTree` в `right`. И так пока не рухнет стек.

[[@Kobayashi_Maru](/users/1627/kobayashi_maru)](/users/1627/kobayashi_maru) подсказал верное направление, но неверно его сформулировал. Нужно как-то так:

```
 public void add(Tree aTree) {

    if (right == null) {
        right = aTree;
    } else if (middle == null) {
        middle = aTree;
    } else if (left == null) {
        left = aTree;
    } else if if (left != null) {
        left.add(aTree);
    } else if (middle != null) {
        middle.add(aTree);
    } else if (right != null) {
        right.add(aTree);
    }

    System.out.print(" " + aTree.key);
}
```

**UPD0**. Формально, мой вариант тоже не совсем корректен. После заполнения всех трех листьев будет заполняться только левое поддерево. **Очевидно, не хватает условия, определяющего, в какое поддерево будет отправлен элемент.**

Comment: Странный алгоритм. Несбалансированный. По сути список. Движение вниз *только* по левой ветви. ТС хочет этого ???

Тут не понятно, **что** ТС хочет. Дерево поиска по ключам или сбалансированное дерево (где то, что она называет ключ, это не ключ поиска, а данные узла).

Для просто сбалансированного дерева IMHO с каждым линком надо хранить вес поддерева и вставлять в поддерево с минимальным весом. 

Возможно имеет смысл обобщить задачу и строить n-арное дерево.

Comment: именно это я и имел ввиду, просто дал подсказку в каком направлении двигаться ;)

Comment: @avp, абсолютно согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь конструкцией if-else if или просто if-else. Смысл писать сначала, что right == null, а потом наоборот? Проще написать так

```
if (right == null ) {right = aTree; }
else if ( right!= null ) {right.add( aTree );}
```

или так

```
if (right == null ) {right = aTree; }
else {right.add( aTree );}
```

Comment: Я думаю, смысл в том, чтобы в троичном дереве заполнять сначала пустые листы слева направо, а только потом уже поддеревья.

В вашем варианте будет строиться только правая ветка.

Comment: нет, ну так для каждой ветки сделать можно,
я просто написал то, что копилятор ругается на неправильную конструкцию проверки значений..

Comment: @Ksenia, а что Вы хотите от этого дерева ? Какими свойствами оно должно обладать ? Как думаете его использовать ?

Ответите на вопросы и сами поймете как правильно заполнить дерево.

Comment: @Ksenia, тогда может быть вам не стоит заполнять дерево от корня? А просто собрать его вручную, а потом считать на здоровье?

    Tree subTreeA = new Tree(67);
    subTreeA.add(new Tree(4));
    subTreeA.add(new Tree(45));

    Tree subTreeB = new Tree(5);
    subTreeB.add(new Tree(30));
    subTreeB.add(new Tree(72));

    Tree subTreeC = new Tree(12);
    subTreeC.add(new Tree(14));
    subTreeC.add(new Tree(95));

    Tree myTree = new Tree(9000);
    myTree.add(subTreeA);
    myTree.add(subTreeB);
    myTree.add(subTreeC);

Comment: Тогда для каждого поддерева узла кроме ссылки на поддерево надо держать счетчик элементов поддерева. Когда направляете очередной элемент в поддерево - увеличивайте соответствующий счетчик.

Если порядок ключей не важен, то наиболее разумным представляется отправка элемента в поддерево с минимальным счетчиком.

Comment: @Ksenia, Вы лучше ответ правьте (там форматирование кода работает). Добавьте **Upd 1** и потом код. Потом его и правьте.

Answer (score 0):

[@Ksenia](/users/7201/ksenia), все будут Вам признательны если Вы будете писать ***какая конкретно ошибка возникает***. У Вас очевидно

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

и это естественно. Смотрите, Вы добавляете новое дерево сначала в right (т.к. rigth вначале null), потом в middle и left. Потом выполняется if (left != null) и Вы добавляете aTree туда еще раз. Поскольку в этот момент **left уже не null !!!**.

Все зацикливается.

Добавьте else после **каждого** if, как в ответе [@Nofate](/users/1984/nofate).

Печать будет несколько "*странная*" т.к. key вставляемого aTree будет печататься на каждом уровне дерева (на всем пути *от листа к корню*).

Этот ли результат Вы на самом деле хотели получить ? Не знаю.